# AspNet Visual Studio - Error while merging assemblies

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, merge

This is occurring on visual studio 2019 community v 16.8.1 on a windows 10 PC.

I need help trying to find the cause for this error that happens at the end of publishing an asp.net 4.7 web project during the merge assemblies step.

**"An error occurred when merging assemblies: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. "**

The merge line looks like
"D:\Repo\project\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Merge.5.0.0-beta2\tools\net40\aspnet_merge.exe" "D:\Repo\project\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir" -o WebBuild -copyattrs obj\Release\AssemblyInfo\AssemblyInfo.dll -a

I added -errorstack to get this result

```
[NullReferenceException]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.Compilation.WebCompilationVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCall call)
   at System.Compiler.StandardVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
   at System.Compiler.StandardVisitor.VisitExpressionStatement(ExpressionStatement statement)
   at System.Compiler.StandardVisitor.VisitStatementList(StatementList statements)
   at System.Compiler.StandardVisitor.VisitBlock(Block block)
   at System.Compiler.StandardVisitor.VisitStatementList(StatementList statements)
   at System.Compiler.StandardVisitor.VisitBlock(Block block)
   at System.Compiler.StandardVisitor.VisitMethod(Method method)
   at System.Compiler.StandardVisitor.VisitMemberList(MemberList members)
   at System.Compiler.StandardVisitor.VisitTypeNode(TypeNode typeNode)
   at System.Web.Compilation.WebCompilationVisitor.VisitClass(Class Class)
   at System.Compiler.StandardVisitor.VisitTypeNodeList(TypeNodeList types)
   at System.Web.Compilation.WebCompilationVisitor.VisitTypeNodeList(TypeNodeList types)
   at System.Compiler.StandardVisitor.VisitModule(Module module)
   at System.Compiler.StandardVisitor.VisitAssembly(AssemblyNode assembly)
   at System.Web.Compilation.WebCompilationVisitor.VisitAssembly(AssemblyNode assembly)
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
   at System.Web.Compilation.Merge.DoMerge(ILMerge merge)
   at System.Web.Compilation.Merge.MergeToSingleAssembly(String outputFile, String[] inputAssemblies, Hashtable assemblyMapping, DirectoryInfo inputDirectory, DirectoryInfo outputDirectory)
   at System.Web.Compilation.Merge.Main(String[] args)
```

But none of the above is telling me what the issue is.

I've tried updating to latest visual studio (2019 community v 16.8.1),
I've removed visualstudio and vscommon folders from /local/microsoft.
Restarted PC.

This issue started after the following windows update.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4586781/windows-10-update-kb4586781

Not sure if the update plays a part but I could publish fine prior to it. The update would have force quit visual studio.

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 1):

It seems that running the profiler had changed the web.config

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.1" assemblyPostProcessorType="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.AspPerformanceInstrumenter, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.AspNetHelper, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
```

Cutting out **assemblyPostProcessorType="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.AspPerformanceInstrumenter, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.AspNetHelper, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"** from this tag

and removing

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.AspNetHelper" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <codeBase version="16.0.0.0" href="file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio/Shared/Common/VSPerfCollectionTools/vs2019/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.AspNetHelper.DLL" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="VsWebSite.Interop" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <codeBase version="8.0.0.0" href="file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio/Shared/Common/VSPerfCollectionTools/vs2019/VsWebSite.Interop.DLL" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Allow the publish to work