# Visual Studio - aspnet_merge.exe error when publishing

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, publishing, aspnet-merge

I've had this issue over VS 2015, 2017 and 2019, so I believe this is not specific to my setup.

`aspnet_merge(0,0): Error occurred: An error occurred when merging assemblies: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

This happens after the following runs:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\aspnet_merge.exe (project location)\TempPackageBuildDir\obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir -o (name of assembly) -copyattrs (repository location)\..\..\TempPackageBuildDir\obj\Debug\AssemblyInfo\AssemblyInfo.dll -a -debug`

I can run this exact same command on a different machine and it runs without an issue. I've been able to solve this ONCE before by explicitly setting my output directory in website.publishproj to

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\TempPackageBuildDir\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But a couple days later the issue came back.  There is somethinng bad cached on my machine specifically and I don't have enough knowledge to know what it is.

Any insight would be appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

**Actually**, the issue is related to your project and VS environment. Please try the following steps:

**1)** [clean all nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or just delete `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`

Close, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin` and `obj` folder.

**Also**, delete all files under `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

**Then**, restart VS, run `update-package -reinstall` under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console**

If you reference any assembly dlls, please remove them first and then add them back.

Make sure that all the Merge's DLLS are not corrupted.

**2)** reset all vs settings under **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset all Settings**

**3)** disable any third party installed extensions to check whether there is one caused that.

**4)** [repair vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) from `vs_installer`

**Besides**, [check whether you have these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64815709/aspnet-visual-studio-error-while-merging-assemblies) on `web.config` file. If you have, please remove them.